# Yii2 как сформировать post запрос на другой url?

Tags: php, yii2, post, get

У меня есть node который находится по адресу http://localhost:3004/

Мне надо сделать post запрос из фреймворка Yii2 на этот узел.

Как мне сформировать post запрос на подобии fetch запроса в java script ?

```
fetch('/article/fetch/user.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    alert(response.headers.get('Content-Type')); // application/json; 
    charset=utf-8
    alert(response.status); // 200

    return response.json();
   })
  .then(function(user) {
    alert(user.name); // iliakan
  })
  .catch( alert );
```

Comment: Используйте guzzlehttp

Comment: Спасибо, я ещё стандартный Yii2 плагин посмотрел. Скажите пожалуйста мне путь в urlManager надо путь к модулю прописать, где про это почитать можно ?

Comment: Здесь хорошо описано про урлы https://p0vidl0.info/yii2-api-guides/guide-ru-runtime-routing.html